# How to get all pixels from a Rect?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, pixel, rectangles

I have a `Rect` drawn on my `Canvas`. In my rectangle I've drawn a `Bitmap`, which has a different resolution than the rectangle itself.

Now I want to get each individual pixel of that bitmap image. I first tried using `Bitmap.getPixels(...)`, but I soon realized that I got way fewer pixels than there were on the screen. I think this is because it gets the pixels of the image I imported, not from what is drawn in the rectangle.

So, I need to get the pixels from the rectangle, not the bitmap. Is there some (custom) method that could do that?

Comment: You can use canvas.drawBitmap(...)

Comment: I'm using that already, but I use `drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dest, Paint paint)`. I fill in `null` for `src` and the rectangle for `dest`, so it scales to the rectangle.

Comment: Do you just need the color of the pixel? You can use the robot class for this one.

Comment: @DFJ I think the robot class captures the screen, and that's not really what I want. I actually need to get the alpha values of each pixel in the rectangle, using the bitmap or rectangle instance.